# Cannot Pass Array from Powershell to C# Runspace Results

Tags: c#, powershell, invoke

I am trying to get a list of database sizes to go from Powershell into a c# combobox, however I get no results.  After furious googling I am still unsure of where to start. How can the $AllDB array be returned to c# as a result?  Is this an Object type issue (which I tried many iterations of) or something concept I am missing? If I just run a basic cmdlet everything works and will populate the combobox (eg. Get-Process)

Also the code outputs the DB names and sizes to the console just fine, Out-String and Out-Default didn't work either.

Powershell code:

```
    foreach ($db in Get-MailboxDatabase -identity exchangeserver\nameprefix*) 
    {
    $mountedServer = $db.ServerName
    $edbFilePath = $db.edbFilePath.PathName
    $path = "`\`\" + $mountedServer + "`\" + $edbFilePath.Split(":")[0].ToString() + "$"+ $edbFilePath.Split(":")[1].ToString()
    $dbsize = Get-ChildItem $path
    $ReturnedObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    DatabaseIdentity = $db.Name
    Size = [Math]::Round($dbsize.Length/1gb, 2)
}
    $AllDB +=$ReturnedObj

}
 $AllDB |Sort-Object Size|convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""}| % { $_ -replace ',', " "}
```

C# Code:

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            ps.AddCommand(script);
            var results = ps.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject result in results)
            {
                comboboxID.Items.Add(result);
            }
        }
        runspace.Close();
    }
```

Comment: "the code outputs the DB names and sizes to the console just fine" - where? When you run it in `powershell.exe`? Or inside a C# application?

Comment: the code runs fine In Powershell

Comment: I think you're focusing on the wrong thing (output formatting) here - it might be that it fails (in C#) because you haven't imported the Exchange module in the runspace and called `Connect-ExchangeServer` - leading the `Get-MailboxDatabase` call to fail and `$AllDB` to be empty

Comment: No, $AllDB get data and can output fine.  I do the connection in the beginning, Like I said it runs fine but the part that doesn't work is the returning of the array to C# in the results part.

Comment: Results is just empty no matter what I do.

Comment: OOps looks like you are right, I fired up the error stream and got: The term 'Get-MailboxDatabase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. How do I fix that

Comment: You ["set up" the exchange management shell environment](http://serverfault.com/a/698220/105072) inside your script (before calling `Get-MailboxDatabase`)

Comment: I ended up needing to just change the App.config file as it wasn't allowing the older add in.  No changes to the PS or c# script were needed.

Comment: Cool, add it as an answer :)